# how to efficiently maintain one file with max size limit but appending new to end of the file

Tags: android, logging, writefile

in an Android app, need to write some data to a file. And the file cannot over the max size. If it reaches the max size it should remove top/old data and append new data to the file (like rolling up).

It could be done by read in the file and remove same amount of data as the new one to be appended to make space for the new data to be written/appended. But it is not efficient since every time it needs to read in whole file to do the cut and write back.

If using two files to rotate it may lost some data. I.e. when both files are full, then delete one file to start from beginning, some of the old data are lost.

Anyone has suggestion to do it efficiently?

Comment: use `RandomAccessFile` as a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer)

Answer (score 1):

> it may lost some data. I.e. when both files are full, then delete one file to start from beginning, some of the old data are lost.

If you are rotating and deleting files of course something will be lost. But you can control how the old data is deleted, for example only delete the oldest but keep the newer data. In this case, just name your files with a timestamp and everytime you want to free space, just sort the files by name (i.e. the timestamp) and delete the oldest one.

> it is not efficient since every time it needs to read in whole file to do the cut and write back.

Usually rotating files should not be modifying the individual file contents. You can split the files into smaller sizes, and maintain a list of files with a total maximum size, e.g. 1MB per file with total 10MB, so you delete the oldest file whenever the data expend to the 11th and keep only 10 newest files.